# The grammar of the "to" in "waiting close by to..."

Tags: grammar

> It doesn't really depend in baseball. The standard terminology is "come up to bat".
>
> Before his turn, a batter is always in the close by "on deck" circle waiting*. He is always the next one to bat when he's in the on deck circle. He is the next player who will "come up to bat". So when the batter ahead of him is done, he comes up to bat (he walks to home base and takes his position).
>
> No matter where they are sitting in the stadium, or even if they are listening on the radio at home, one fan will ask another, "Who's coming up** next?"
>
> *. the turn of a batter in baseball lasts only a couple of minutes, at most, unlike cricket. It's not uncommon to last only twenty seconds. So there is always another batter waiting close by ***to*** take his place.
>
> ** the "up" likely comes from the fact that the other players on the team sit in the "dugout" when one of their teammates is batting. It's partway below ground level so there are a couple of steps to walk up to get onto the field. So a player literally has to go up to reach the batting area (first the on deck circle and then home plate).

[Source](https://forum.wordreference.com/threads/comes-up-to-bat.4041701/#post-20749918)

> I'm waiting **to** go into the theatre
> I'm waiting for the theatre doors **to** open.

"**to**"s don't have anything to do with "purpose". They mean "I am waiting because the doors aren't open yet", and I wouldn't be able rephrase my sentence to "I'm waiting in order to go into the theatre".

Are "**to**"s and ***to*** the same?

Comment: Please [cite the sources of quoted texts](https://ell.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1084/so-you-found-a-sentence-or-phrase-why-you-should-cite-your-source).

Comment: It is not clear what you are asking.,  Can you please ask again, with different words?

Comment: "there is always another batter waiting close by in order to take his place" is OK. It's expressing purpose. "We're waiting for the rain to stop" is different - there "to" is an infinitive marker accompanying the word "stop". It's not clear which sentence you're actually troubled by or what your problem is.

Comment: @StuartF "there is always another batter waiting close by to take his place" - there "to" could also be an infinitive marker accompanying the word "take". It could also be not expressing purpose.

Comment: @StuartF I've edited my post to make it more clear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"to" is the subordinator that introduces the infinitive phrase "to take his place". And it does indeed give the **purpose** of the batter waiting close by. So this is an infinitive of purpose.

> There is another batter who is waiting nearby.  This batter will take the place of one "at bat". That is his purpose.

Comment: Is the "to" in "hurry up, we're waiting close by to go" an infinitive of purpose even though the "to" in "hurry up, we're waiting to go" is not an infinitive of purpose?

Comment: Its an infinitive.  That is the grammar. The "of purpose" is part of the meaning. What is the meaning of "We are waiting to go"  Does not "to go" tell you why they are waiting?